# How to get the username of a logged in user and compare it to get the id

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I want to be able to get the username of the logged in user in my C# ASP.net application so I can get the ID of that user. I then want to perform an edit so they can apply to be part of an appointment.

With my current code, I click the link and I just get a HTTP 400 error. I have debugged this and the ID is coming through as the correct value. Is there any reason that its not being attached to the url?

```
// GET: 
    public ActionResult VolunteerCeremony(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }

        string userName = string.Empty;

        //if (System.Web.HttpContext.Current != null &&
        //    System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        //{
        //    System.Web.Security.MembershipUser usr = System.Web.Security.Membership.GetUser();
        //    if (usr != null)
        //    {
        //        userName = usr.UserName;
        //    }
        //}

        var getVolunteerId = (from u in db.Volunteers
                              where WebSecurity.CurrentUserName == u.Username
                              select u.VolunteerId).FirstOrDefault();


        Volunteer volunteer = db.Volunteers
            .Include(p => p.Appointments)
            .Where(i => getVolunteerId == id)
            .FirstOrDefault();

        if (volunteer == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        PopulateAssignedCeremonyData(volunteer);
        return View(volunteer);
    }

    // POST: /Player/Edit/5
    // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
    // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult VolunteerCeremony(int? id, string[] selectedOptions)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }

        var getVolunteerId = (from u in db.Volunteers
                              where WebSecurity.CurrentUserName == u.Username
                              select u.VolunteerId).FirstOrDefault();


        var updateVolunteerWithCeremony = db.Volunteers
            .Include(p => p.Appointments)
            .Where(i => getVolunteerId == id)
            .Single();

        try
        {
            UpdateVolunteerCeremonies(selectedOptions, updateVolunteerWithCeremony);

            db.Entry(updateVolunteerWithCeremony).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        catch (RetryLimitExceededException /* dex */)
        {
            //Log the error (uncomment dex variable name and add a line here to write a log.
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Unable to save changes. Try again, and if the problem persists, see your system administrator.");
        }


        PopulateAssignedCeremonyData(updateVolunteerWithCeremony);
        return View(updateVolunteerWithCeremony);
    }
```

**EDIT** This is where I'm calling the method

```
else if(Request.IsAuthenticated && HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole("Volunteer"))
                    {
                        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Appointments", "Create", "Appointments")</li>
                        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Join Ceremony", "VolunteerCeremony", "Volunteers")</li>
                    }
```

**EDIT 2** Here's my ViewModel that I used for the many to many relationship I have:

```
public class VolunteerCeremonyVM
{
    public int AppointmentId { get; set; }
    public string DetailsOfAppointment { get; set; }
    public bool Assigned { get; set; }

    public VolunteerCeremonyVM()
    {
        this.AppointmentId = AppointmentId;
        this.DetailsOfAppointment = DetailsOfAppointment;
        this.Assigned = Assigned;
    }

}
```

Comment: "so I can the ID of that user" what you mean there ?

Comment: what type of authentication is use for eample for windows authentication you can use Request.LogonUserIdentity.Name.Split('\\')[1]

Comment: @dimmik sorry I mean get the id

Comment: "It isn't getting the ID from my LINQ query even though I debugged it and the ID is coming through" - this is a rather confusing sentence. You seem to be saying the ID isn't coming through but that when you debug it is - can you be more clear on this? Does it work when you debug but not when you don't? Also you say "Is there any reason that its not being attached to the url?" but I am unclear on what part of your code is actually trying to put this ID in any kind of url....

Comment: @Chris I just edited my question as it was very confusing. I essentially copied the edit method and modified as they were similar. When I press a button, I want the volunteer to get to this method but its not going onto the url like it would when I press edit

Comment: @AnnaDoe I'm assuming the problem is in your POST method, is that correct?

Can you include the code where you generate the POST form and/or the call to the POST action? Depending on the setup, it's most likely not passing the ID through correctly.

Comment: Hi @ScottBaldric please find the edit updated with the details requested

Comment: @AnnaDoe Thanks for the followup. ActionLink generates a GET request. If you want access to the POST version of VolunteerCeremony you will need to have an Html.BeginForm() somewhere that starts a form for submitting the form with its selected options. Do you have code showing that? Also, just to clarify, is the problem with the first method, the second method, or both?

Comment: @ScottBaldric both methods work fine, when I click the link, it brings me a 400 error. I then put the ID of the current user in and it takes me to that page, VolunteerCeremony, and allows me to view and mess around with the data

Comment: @ScottBaldric I have been getting a null pointer with the links also

Comment: @AnnaDoe Check my answer and let me know how it works. The most likely issue is that you have not told the ActionLink's or the Forms the ID that you're passing along.

Without knowing more about where the Null Reference Exception is occurring, I can't help with that. I would recommend opening a new question if you can't find it detailing your reproduction steps. I would also encourage you to read the following link: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Based on further clarification, you will want to update your ViewModel to include a `VolunteerId`. So it should look something like:

```
public class VolunteerCeremonyVM
{
    public int AppointmentId { get; set; }
    public string DetailsOfAppointment { get; set; }
    public bool Assigned { get; set; }
    public int VolunteerId { get; set; }
}
```

Notice that I removed the default constructor as it wasn't doing anything. When you construct the object you can use code like the following:

```
var model = new VolunteerCeremonyVM {
    AppointmentId = 10,
    VolunteerId = 50,
    //etc
};
```

As this will set all of the properties after the basic object is constructed.

Then, you will want to pass this view model into the view that is generating your action links like so: `return View(model);` in whatever controller action you're using.

Inside the view, you will make use of this new information. Specifically, the `Html.ActionLink` method requires that any extra parameters are passed to it in a route dictionary. It uses this route dictionary to build the URL that is generated for the anchor tag. You can call `Html.ActionLink` with an anonymous object for its fourth parameter to specify the route dictionary. The `id` will be the name of the parameter and `Model.VolunteerId` will be the value of the current volunteer.

Change the `Html.ActionLink` call to the following to pass an id:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Join Ceremony",
    "VolunteerCeremony",
    "Volunteers",
    new { id = Model.VolunteerId },
    null)
```

This should fill in the id parameter of the ActionLink with the currently logged in user's userId which should generate the following link: `/Volunteers/VolunteerCeremony/3` or whatever the ID actually is.

For the form side, you will also need a hidden field on the form so the correct id is sent along with the request. You will need to add a `VolunteerId` to the form ViewModel that you create when generating the form page. Once you've done that, inside the form itself, you will need to add the following:

```
Html.Hidden("id", Model.VolunteerId)
```

This creates an `<input type="hidden" name="id" value="3" />` tag that will be sent with the form on post back to the server. Since the tag's name is `id` this will match with the `id` that's defined in your controller action.

Comment: Might as well tell you here! Your code gets rid of the null pointer but I'm still getting the 400 error

Comment: When you debug are you seeing the id come through? Or do you see it in the URL when you click the link after making the above change?

Comment: When I click the link I get the following on the url: "http://localhost:9755/Volunteers/VolunteerCeremony"

Comment: Would also be handy for me to mention that in my code, I don't want to use the user id generated by the registering, I have my own volunteer id that I want to use. They will be different

Comment: Okay. In that case, you will need to pass the id to the View as a property on a ViewModel. Do you have a ViewModel for the page that these links are being generated on?

Comment: Updated my answer there Scott, maybe I need to have the VolunteerId in the ViewModel also?

Comment: Correct you will want to include the VolunteerId. I will update my answer showing some examples.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164993/discussion-between-scott-baldric-and-anna-doe).